# Why didn't Vision defend himself against Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* when Thanos reversed time and brought Vision back to life, he rips the stone out without any resistance. This seems quite odd to me noting that each time Corvus Glaive attempted to take the stone there was a struggle or attempt to resist, albeit the Vision was never truly successful in overcoming Corvus. But why was he reluctant to resist in the case of Thanos?

Answer (score 6):

It seems partly because he was already weakened and he was resigned to it already happening. There was nothing more that he could do.

Previously in the Battle of Wakanda he had been stabbed by Corvus Glaive *again*<sup>1</sup> which weakened him quite a lot. When Wanda lands next to him to begin the Stone destruction Vision is laying on the floor with next to no life in him. He knows the only chance they have is to not fight but instead kill him by destroying the Stone.

Which leads into the next point: when time is reversed and he comes back to life Wanda and Thanos have switched positions with all the Avengers swept aside. He can’t fight anymore himself and everyone else has easily been defeated. He’s resigned himself to the fact that he will no longer be able to defeat Thanos.

Lastly, **time**. From all of sudden, from his perspective, Wanda and Thanos have swapped places. This is confusing and so whilst he’s working out what’s happened Thanos grabs him and chokes him out meaning he can’t really fight back anyway. *Then* Thanos grabs the Stone to rip it out causing a great deal of pain *again* lowering his chances to fight back. There just wasn’t really the time or opportunity to do so.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>*It appears Vision never fully healed from the first stabbing by Glaive in Scotland as well. He was weak before the Battle of Wakanda even began and he was injured even more. He just didn't have the fight left in him.*</sub>

Comment: Ahhh! Makes perfect sense

Comment: Chokes out a robot?

Comment: @T.J.L. Vision isn't exactly a robot, he's more of an android _and_ he's made from the synthetic flesh like stuff Cho can make.